# Stored procedure access from form

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I have the following code:

```
string connectionString = "<REDACTED>";



            using (SqlConnection invoiceConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("dbo.sInvoiceBySchool", invoiceConnection);

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@School", SqlDbType.Int);
                command.Parameters["@School"].Value = schoolNumber.Value;

                invoiceConnection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
```

The output consistently returns error 201, "Message = Procedure or function 'sInvoiceBySchool' expects parameter '@School', which was not supplied.". I am supplying the value that the procedure wants using a numericupdown, then use a button to run the code.

I've also tried writing the value directly into the code, with the same result. Have I formatted the parameters properly?

Comment: @SonerGönül Yes, positive. Can you expand on where I should place `CommandType.StoredProcedure`?

Comment: @RoteKatze: Can you debug and see what is the value of `schoolNumber.Value` ??

Comment: There are two problems. AddWithValue, expects as second parameter, the value not the type. The CommandType should be set to CommandType.StoredProcedure

Comment: @huMptyduMpty It validly takes on whatever value I place in the numericupdown.

Comment: @Steve No? The formatting remains the same according to this msdn article = http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem you missing [SqlCommand.CommandType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Add

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: Voila! That did it. Appreciate the actual example too.

Comment: +1 This has hurt me more times that I care to admit.

Answer (score 1):

AddwithValue method takes two params. One for parameter name, the other is the value

Try

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@School", schoolNumber.Value);

And I think there is one more error. You have to specify this query is stored procedure with

command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure (or something like this)